# Remove wrapping <a> anchor tag from an image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I am trying to remove the first wrapping  tag of an image **IF one exists**

```
   <div class="feature">
        <a>
          <img width="252" height="79" alt="" src="http://localhost:81/site/wp-
          content/uploads/2011/12/home-highlights.jpg" title="home-highlights" 
          class="alignnone size-full wp-image-55">
        </a>
   </div>
```

I've had a look at a number of options and I assume my approach is correct here:

```
$(".feature img").closest('a').remove();
```

If I use the example above,it removes the image too which is not what I want of course.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

jQuery has a built-in function for it: `unwrap`:

```
$(".feature a > img").unwrap();
```

`unwrap` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

`child(>)` selector [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

> Description: Selects all **direct child** elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

***Thanks @am not i am!***
**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/csVfZ/)**

Comment: +1, Though you could simplify a bit by checking for the `a` element in the selector... `$(".feature a > img").unwrap();` :)

Comment: @amnotiam. Is there any significant difference between my(yours answer...) and rich.okelly? This one should be more efficient, right?

Comment: @gdoron: I'd bet that yours is a little quicker, but in most cases the difference would be negligible, and would probably vary between different implementations.

Comment: Thanks @gdoron this helped me as of 2015!

Answer (score 6):

The [unwrap method](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) is the one you want:

```
 $(".feature a").children('img').unwrap();
```

Comment: This is the most effective answer.

Comment: Only problem with this is the "IF one exists" part of the question.  If the img is not wrapped in an `a` tag this will remove whatever other parent it has.

Comment: Thans Rich. Your option was the same as Doron's ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, it will remove the element and any children elements. Try this though, save the image as a variable and replace the html of the div:

```
var myImg = $('.feature img');
$('.feature').html(myImg);
```